# Parsing a command line command without string library

Tags: c

So i am trying to parse a command from a command line like:

```
cd /mnt/cdrom
```

comes to

- name = "cd"
- argc = 2
- argv = {"cd", "/mnt/cdrom", NULL}

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
void parse(char* line, command_t* command) {

    // TODO: Check if string is empty or null
        while (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\0')
     i++;

     if (line[i] == ' ') {

         }

    // TODO: Split the string on whitespace -> should become an array of char
    // TODO: The first string is the command, the length of tokens[1:] is the length of the arguments, and tokens[1:] are the arguments
    // TODO: Create/fill-in the command struct with the data from above
}
```

That is as far as i have made it im not really sure how to split it at this point without string functions.

Comment: 1) Why without ``string.h``? 2) What exactly are you trying to parse? If your command line would be like ``my cd /mnt/cdrom``, or even with spaces ``my cd "/home/my directory"`` you will receive correct arguments ``argv[0] = my, argv[1] = cd, argv[2] = /home/my directory``.

Comment: Sorry,I was not clear i am making my own shell and i need the parse the command entered by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's in haste solution, but it works.. Of course you need to dynamically allocate memory in parse function with some kind of `list` for example (for different arguments) and some kind of buffer for current argument processing.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_TOKEN  5
#define MAX_LENGTH 64

void copy_str( char* dst, char* src, int size ) {
    int i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
}

char** parse( char* line, int size, int* argc ) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char** argv = NULL;
    argv = (char**)calloc( MAX_TOKEN, sizeof(char*) );
    for( i = 0; i < MAX_TOKEN; ++i ) {
        argv[i] = (char*)calloc( MAX_LENGTH, sizeof(char) );
    }
    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        if( line[i] == ' ' ) {
            copy_str( argv[*argc], line + j, i - j );
            j = i + 1; // length of token
            (*argc)++;
        }
    }
    // copy last
    copy_str( argv[*argc], line + j, i - j );
    (*argc)++;
    return argv;
}

int main( ) {
    int t = 0, i;
    char* s = "cd /mnt/cdrom";
    char** argv = parse( s, 13, &t );
    for( i = 0; i < t; ++i ) {
        printf( "%s\n", argv[i] );
    }
    t = 0;
    s = "ls -l /home/";
    argv = parse( s, 12, &t );
    for( i = 0; i < t; ++i ) {
        printf( "%s\n", argv[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For dynamicly allocating memory could i use malloc?

Comment: Yes, I use ``calloc`` only to fill allocated memory with zeros.

Comment: So what exactly would changed if i used malloc? argv = (char**)malloc( sizeof(char*) );

Comment: If you want to use ``malloc`` you change ``,`` with ``*``, like ``argv = (char**)malloc( MAX_TOKEN * sizeof(char*) );``